# Probability of winning a game that ends after one player gets 3 wins in a row

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**Question:**

In  a game with two people, there is a draw half of the time. The other half of the time, player A wins with 2/3 and player B wins with 1/3. The game ends once a player wins three games in a row. What is the probability A wins?

**Approach:**

I am thinking that this is somewhat similar to asking what is the probability of getting HHH before TTT. However, you need to compute the probability of each player winning in a round and not having a draw.

Let $P(A)$ probability A wins, let $P(B)$ be probability $B$ wins:

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{6} \quad P(B) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Let $E$ be the event that we get $AAA$ before $BBB$. However, I am not sure if we can use the below approach because I think we may violate the total law of probability. I am not sure how I can include a third draws? Do I add $P(\text{draw})P(E)$ to each of these? because if it is a draw, we restart...

$$P(E) = P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(B)P(E|B_1)$$

$$P(E|A_1) = P(A)P(E|A_1A_2) + P(B)P(E|A_1B_2) = P(A)P(E|A_1A_2) + P(B)P(E|B_1)$$

$$P(E|A_1A_2)= P(A)P(E|A_1A_2A_3) + P(B)P(E|A_1A_2B_3) = P(A) + P(B)P(E|B_1)$$

$$P(E|B_1) = P(A)P(E|B_1A_2) + P(B)P(E|B_1B_2) = P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(B)P(E|B_1B_2)$$

$$P(E|B_1B_2)= P(A)P(E|B_1B_2A_3) + P(B)P(E|B_1B_2B_3) = P(A)P(E|A_1) + 0$$

Substituting:

$$P(E|B_1) = P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1)$$

$$P(E|A_1A_2)= P(A) + P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(B)P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1)$$

$$P(E|A_1) =  P(A)P(A) + P(A)P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(A)P(B)P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1) + P(B)P(B)P(A)P(E|A_1)$$
etc...

But this seems very messy ...

Answer (score 2):

Note:  I am assuming that draws kill the current winning streak.  That is to say, if $A$ wins the first two games, draws the third, and then $A$ wins the fourth, $A$ is now just on a one game streak.

Proceed by states. Denote the current state of a game by $(X,n)$  Where $X\in \{A,B\}$ denotes the player currently on a winning streak and $n$ denotes the length of the winning streak.  We let $\emptyset$ denote the starting state as well as any state in which the last round ended in a draw.

For a state $(X,n)$ we let $P_{X,n}$ denote the probability that $A$ will eventually win given that we are currently in that state.

We remark that
\begin{align}
P_{A,2} &= \frac 26\times 1+\frac 16\times P_{B,1}+\frac 12\times P_{\emptyset} \\
P_{A,1} &= \frac 26\times P_{A,2}+\frac 16\times P_{B,1}+\frac 12\times P_{\emptyset} \\
P_{B,2} &= \frac 26\times P_{A,1}+\frac 16\times 0+\frac 12\times P_{\emptyset} \\
P_{B,1} &= \frac 26\times P_{A,1}+\frac 16\times P_{B,2}+\frac 12\times P_{\emptyset} \\
P_{\emptyset} &= \frac 26\times P_{A,1}+\frac 16\times P_{B,1}+\frac 12\times P_{\emptyset}
\end{align}

That gives us a solvable linear system.  Barring arithmetic error, I get that $$\boxed{P_{\emptyset}=\frac {86}{99}}$$

[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve++X%3D%282%2F6%29*1%2B%281%2F6%29*W%2B%281%2F2%29*V%2C+Y%3D%282%2F6%29*X%2B%281%2F6%29*W%2B%281%2F2%29*V%2C+Z%3D%282%2F6%29*Y%2B%281%2F6%29*0%2B%281%2F2%29*V%2CW%3D%282%2F6%29*Y%2B%281%2F6%29*Z%2B%281%2F2%29*V%2CV%3D%282%2F6%29*Y%2B%281%2F6%29*W%2B%281%2F2%29*V%2C) is the computation.  There, $X=P_{A,2}, Y=P_{A,1}, Z=P_{B,2}, W=P_{B,1}, V=P_{\emptyset}$

Comment: Very Interesting, somewhat counter-intuitive result, since the relative probabilities are 8 to 1.  I am curious whether you can construct an intuitive (i.e. *hand-waving*) explanation for why the answer is less than 8/9.

Comment: Okay so this is fairly similar to my solution, but I need to account for the case of a draw?

Comment: @user2661923: It would be $\frac89$ if every streak ended in a draw. But a streak may end with a win by the other player, and that slightly favours $B$, since there are more $A$ streaks than $B$ streaks, so $B$ more often gets a head start due to the end of an $A$ streak than vice versa.

Comment: @user2330624 Not sure what you mean.  I have allowed for draws, they pass you back to the starting state $\emptyset$.  If you intended something other than that, you should edit your post to explain.

Comment: @joriki That is a nice explanation, thanks.

Comment: @user2661923  Note that it's even more extreme if you don't have draws at all, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve++X%3D%282%2F3%29*1%2B%281%2F3%29*W%2C+Y%3D%282%2F3%29*X%2B%281%2F3%29*W%2C+Z%3D%282%2F3%29*Y%2B%281%2F3%29*0%2CW%3D%282%2F3%29*Y%2B%281%2F3%29*Z%2CV%3D%282%2F3%29*Y%2B%281%2F3%29*W)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another way to do this, using generating functions.

A match that $A$ wins has the form

$$
\left(B_0^2\left(A_1^2B_1^2\right)_0^\infty A_0^2D\right)_0^\infty B_0^2\left(A_1^2B_1^2\right)_0^\infty A_3^3\;,
$$

where $A$, $B$ and $D$ denote a win for $A$, a win for $B$ and a draw, respectively, and $X_a^b$ means anything from $a$ to $b$ repetitions of $X$. That is, we optionally start with up to two wins by $B$; then we have any number of repetitions of first $A$ then $B$ winning one or two games; then $A$ optionally wins up to two games; then a draw; this entire sequence can be repeated any number of times (possibly none) and then the same once more except now ending in three wins by $A$.

With $x$, $y$, $z$ denoting the probabilities for $A$ winning, $B$ winning and a draw, respectively, and with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k=(1-q)^{-1}$, this corresponds to the generating function

$$
\left(1-\left(1+y+y^2\right)\left(1-\left(x+x^2\right)\left(y+y^2\right)\right)^{-1}\left(1+x+x^2\right)z\right)^{-1}\\\cdot\left(1+y+y^2\right)\left(1-\left(x+x^2\right)\left(y+y^2\right)\right)^{-1}\cdot x^3
\\
=\frac{x^3}{\frac{1-\left(x+x^2\right)\left(y+y^2\right)}{1+y+y^2}-z\left(1+x+x^2\right)}\;.
$$

Substituting the given probabilities $x=\frac13$, $y=\frac16$, $z=\frac12$ yields the probability

$$
\frac{\left(\frac13\right)^3}{\frac{1-\left(\frac13+\left(\frac13\right)^2\right)\left(\frac16+\left(\frac16\right)^2\right)}{1+\frac16+\left(\frac16\right)^2}-\frac12\left(1+\frac13+\left(\frac13\right)^2\right)}=\frac{86}{99}\approx87\%
$$

for $A$ to win the match.